# por que me salta un error null pointer exception?

Tags: java

Tengo una clase llamada departamentos. En un Jframe principal creo un array de objetos de esa clase y le doy valor a las dos primeras posiciones del array:

Así declaro el array:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego desde un Jdialog intento obtener los datos del array para mostrarlos en un textArea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al ejecutarlo me salta null pointer exception en la linea que intenta coger el Numero de departamento.
A que se debe esto si el array tiene valores?

Comment: Por favor, pega siempre el código como texto, no como imagen. Es mucho más fácil copiar y pegar en la respuesta para añadir comentarios o soluciones.

Comment: No has añadido un [mcve], así que no lo puedo asegurar, pero lo más seguro es que Principal (¿es un objeto?, entonces su variable debería empezar con minúscula) sea null